# Every button click adds a dynamic layout to old layout ||Android||

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I have checked everywhere but i couldn't find the answer. I am generating order details dynamically on every click. First click works fine ,But after then, every click adds the new order to old order. Old one is not vanishing. I tried `remove view` but that did not help either. How can i fix that? I want to show every order detail when it is clicked.

```java
@Override
    public void itemClicked(int index, int siparisId) {
        siparis_id = siparisId;

        getSiparisUrunleri(siparis_id);
    }



private void getSiparisDetay(int siparisId) {

linearUrunler = view.findViewById(R.id.linearUrunler);

        for (SiparisUrunleri siparisUrunleri : siparisUrunleriList) {

            linearTxt = new LinearLayout(context);
            linearTxt.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            linearTxt.setWeightSum(10f);
            linearTxt.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView txtUrunAdi = new TextView(context);
            txtUrunAdi.setText(siparisUrunleri.getUrun_adi());
            txtUrunAdi.setId(siparisUrunleri.getId());
            txtUrunAdi.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 8f));
            txtUrunAdi.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);

            TextView txtUrunAdet = new TextView(context);
            txtUrunAdet.setId(siparisUrunleri.getId());
            txtUrunAdet.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0} Adet", siparisUrunleri.getAdet()));
            txtUrunAdet.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
            txtUrunAdet.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);

            TextView txtUrunOlcu = new TextView(context);
            txtUrunOlcu.setId(siparisUrunleri.getId());
            txtUrunOlcu.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0}{1}", parseInputByReplace(siparisUrunleri.getOlcu()), getResources().getString(R.string.meter_square_sign)));
            txtUrunOlcu.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
            txtUrunOlcu.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);

            linearTxt.addView(txtUrunAdi);
            linearTxt.addView(txtUrunAdet);
            linearTxt.addView(txtUrunOlcu);

            linearLayout.addView(linearTxt);
        }

        linearUrunler.addView(linearLayout);

 crdBtnX.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ((ViewGroup) linearUrunler.getParent()).removeView(linearLayout);

                relativeSiparisDetay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
}
```

siparisUrunleriList clears items every closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `removeAllViewsInLayout();` for the parent layout,

for example :

```
linearLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried ```removeallviews``` was crashes before. Now with getParent it works perfectly.Thanks so much

Comment: this is working for who wants clear answer ``` ((ViewGroup) linearLayout.getParent()).removeAllViews();```